# Allowing hotlinks for facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, hotlinking

I am building a site, in which I denied hotlinking of images. But after I added the facebooks "like" link to my pages, I realized that I want to allow hotlinking for facebook. So, if a user likes a page on my site, facebook should be able to show a related thumbnail of the page in the profile of the user. So, I added an exclusion rule in IIS like 
if {HTTP_REFERER} matches pattern ^(https?://)?(\w+.)*facebook.(com|net)(/.*)*$ , allow.
Alas, it didn't work for me. 
After that I googled for an answer. A forum post suggested to use "tfbnw" instead of facebook, so I added that exclusion, too:
^(https?://)?(\w+.)*tfbnw.(com|net)(/.*)*$

But as you might expect, still no chance.
So, I don't know which URL facebook uses to request images when a user uses the like button. I would appreciate any help to uncover this mystery, so that I can allow that URL on my site.

Note: If I disable hotlinking protection, everything works fine. So we know that my problem is just the hotlinking protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try whitelisting with IP address? All of FB's crawlers should come from one of the IP addresses returned by

whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS32934'

Comment: umm.. is this a linux/unix command? unfortunately I am using windows operatings system... I tried to navigate to whois.radb.net but there is no response. In addition, what is that '!gAS32934' for?

Comment: I asked a good friend of mine to execute this command, it returned a large list of IPs like 204.15.20.0/22 
69.63.176.0/20 
66.220.144.0/20 
66.220.144.0/21 
69.63.184.0/21 
69.63.176.0/21 
74.119.76.0/22 
69.171.255.0/24 but I'm not sure whether IIS will understand these (because of /22 , /24 etc)

Comment: They're IP Ranges. I'm not too familiar with IIS, so couldn't say how to enter them, but I'd be shocked if it couldn't do it.

Comment: It allows, but it needs subnet masks instead of /22 /24. So either I'll calculate subnet masks for each ip range (there are lots of them), or I will give up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try allowing the domain `fbcdn.net`:

```
^(https?://)?(\w+.)fbcdn.(com|net)(/.)*$
```

This is facebook's content delivery network.

Comment: nope, this didn't work either. I also tried it with ^(https?://)?(\w+\.)*fbcdn.(com|net)(/.*)*$ and had -again- no chance.. :(